# Unreproducible string comparison, forces elsif failure

Tags: ruby, string-comparison, ruby-1.8

In answering [this code golf question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928563/code-golf-evaluating-mathematical-expressions), I ran across a problem in my answer.

I've been testing this and I cannot even get these two comparisons to work in the code, despite the fact that IRB has the right behavior.  I *really* need some help here.

Here's the code, below that will be an explanation of the problem.

```
def solve_expression(expr)
  chars = expr.split '' # characters of the expression
  parts = []  # resulting parts
  s,n = '','' # current characters

  while(n = chars.shift)
    if (s + n).match(/^(-?)[.\d]+$/) || (!chars[0].nil? && chars[0] != ' ' && n == '-') # only concatenate when it is part of a valid number
      s += n
    elsif (chars[0] == '(' && n[0] == '-') || n == '(' # begin a sub-expression
      p n # to see what it breaks on, ( or -
      negate = n[0] == '-'
      open = 1
      subExpr = ''
      while(n = chars.shift)
        open += 1 if n == '('
        open -= 1 if n == ')'
        # if the number of open parenthesis equals 0, we've run to the end of the
        # expression.  Make a new expression with the new string, and add it to the
        # stack.
        subExpr += n unless n == ')' && open == 0
        break if open == 0
      end
      parts.push(negate ? -solve_expression(subExpr) : solve_expression(subExpr))
      s = ''
    elsif n.match(/[+\-\/*]/)
      parts.push(n) and s = ''
    else
      parts.push(s) if !s.empty?
      s = ''
    end
  end
  parts.push(s) unless s.empty? # expression exits 1 character too soon.

  # now for some solutions!
  i = 1
  a = parts[0].to_f # left-most value is will become the result
  while i < parts.count
    b,c = parts[i..i+1]
    c = c.to_f
    case b
      when '+': a = a + c
      when '-': a = a - c
      when '*': a = a * c
      when '/': a = a / c
    end
    i += 2
  end
  a
end
```

The problem occurs in the assignment of `negate`.

I need negate to be true when the character just before a expression is a dash, but the condition isn't even working.  Both `n == '-'` and `n[0] == '-'`, the form of quotation doesn't matter, wind up FALSE every time.  Yet, I've been using this exact comparison and `n == '('` works correctly every time!

What is going on?  Why doesn't `n == '-'` work, when `n == '('` does?  This is encoded in UTF-8 w/o BOM, UNIX linebreaks.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
if (s + n).match(/^(-?)[.\d]+$/) || (!chars[0].nil? && chars[0] != ' ' && n == '-')
      s += n
elsif (chars[0] == '(' && n[0] == '-') || n == '('
```

As `n` is always a one-character string, if `(chars[0] == '(' && n[0] == '-'))` is true, then the previous condition, `(!chars[0].nil? && chars[0] != ' ' && n == '-')`, will also be true. Your code will never enter the second part of the `if` if `n[0]=='-'`.

If your `p n` line is outputting a dash, be sure it is exactly the same character you are looking for, not some character that *looks like* a dash. Unicode has many kinds of dashes, maybe you have a weird unicode dash character in your code or on your input.

Comment: Thank you very much, it hadn't occurred to me that the previous statement had caught my code.  Thanks for the fresh eyes.