# What is the smallest, simplest CPU that GCC can compile for?

Tags: gcc, cpu, emulation

In terms of instruction set and simplicity of emulation. I would like to implement a virtual CPU and figured why not emulate an existing one, so to be able to compile C code to it.

Comment: Another route is to search for backends to single instruction set architectures: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711443/minimal-instruction-set-to-solve-any-problem-with-a-computer-program People seem to have done a clang backend for subleq: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711443/minimal-instruction-set-to-solve-any-problem-with-a-computer-program/38523869#38523869

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Moxie](http://moxielogic.org/blog) is a great target because it was designed specifically to be an ideal target for GCC.  I am the author and would be happy to answer any questions.  *green at moxielogic dot com*

Comment: Is there reference documentation about the architecture and instructions set?

Comment: What there is exists at http://moxielogic.org/wiki ... although it will take me a bit to undo damage from the wiki vandals.  Check back soon.

Comment: Can Moxie architecture be used in a closed source commercial project (think inclusion of it's emulator in a video game)? On your site I didn't find a license that clearly specifies that.

Comment: Hi @ezolotko.  Thanks for asking.  The answer is, in general, yes.  I'll try to update the docs/website soon, but please contact me directly at green AT moxielogic.com.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

GCC supports [Moxie](http://moxielogic.org/blog/?tag=gcc) (originally [ggx](http://spindazzle.org/ggx/)), a little architecture invented by Anthony Green for experimentation.

You, too, can follow the steps he took to invent your own small simple CPU and port GCC to it.

Answer (score 5):

[ZPU](http://opencores.org/project,zpu) (an FPGA targeted 32bit processor) is very small.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the AVR [ATTiny45](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/product_card.asp?part_id=3618) or similar AVR chip.

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't an uncommon question; I'd hope that most CPU/machine simulation toolkits would include a simple example implementation, but some don't.

I haven't worked with it, but [Knuth's MMIX architecture (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX) looks interesting.  Like Moxie, it was created to "illustrate machine-level aspects of programming" and is simpler than real machines.  It's supported by GCC and there appear to be multiple existing simulators that could be used as a reference in your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something from the Ti [MSP430](http://focus.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?&familyId=911&uiTemplateId=PP-T-GSAT1NU_T&techFamId=null&rootFamilyId=null&sectionId=95&tabId=1527&appId=null&viewDeviceCallingPage=null&totalCount=36&showAdditionalParameters=no&parameter=2554204427&lc=2001227&lc=2001219&lc=2000886&lc=2000121&lc=2001132&lc=2000061&lc=2000158&compare=yes&download=yes&sort=yes&customize=yes&paramResults=yes&paramCriteria=yes&familyTree=yes&military=no&baSystem=yes&paramTable=no&sortOption=PA_SUB_FAMILY_NAME&sortMode=ASC&searchPaths=1000911&pageId=911&templateId=0&navigationId=0&family=mcu&paramTable=no&military=no&&uiTemplateId=PP-T-GSAT1NU_T&techFamId=null&rootFamilyId=null&sectionId=95&tabId=1527&appId=null&viewDeviceCallingPage=null&resetCompare=true#sdp) series.

Answer (score 1):

MIPS I (one of the targets of GCC) is a surprisingly easy-to-emulate 32-bit platform. Here is an short and simple emulator which can load and run a statically linked Linux MIPS I executable: https://github.com/pts/pts-mips-emulator