# What is the purpose of SUB Instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm learning assembly on my own, I have a confusion that I would like to clear.

So from what I understand a x86 computer uses the same circuit for addition and subtraction. For subtraction a negative number is converted to its 2 complement and then the addition circuit could be used to carry out the subtraction. Eg: The equation `4 - 2` is converted to `4 + (-2)`

So if subtraction can be done using the 2 complement then what is the purpose of the `SUB` Instruction?

Comment: To do it in a single cycle.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth can you please explain it in details ?

Comment: A better question is: Why do we need the add instruction? An add can done using AND/OR and shifts.

Comment: An even better question: why do we need programmers at all? :-)

Comment: @Mysticial Another question: why do whe need bitwise instructions? You can do all of that with only add or sub, although a bit long

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the 2's complement world, the negation of an integer can be obtained by taking the 1's complement (all bits inverted) and adding 1. For example, using 8-bit arithmetic:

```
A:   0x00000002    ; my number
~A:  0xFFFFFFFD    ; 1's complement of my number
-A:  0xFFFFFFFE    ; 2's complement of my number (negative A)
```

To subtract `A-B`, surely we can add the negative, `A+(-B)`:

```
NOT  B              ; invert each bit in the 8-bit value, B
ADD  B, 1           ; add 1, giving the 2's complement negated B
ADD  A, B
```

And of course I had to modify `B` (negate it) before I could add it. What if I wanted `B` to stay intact?

```
PUSH B              ; save B
NOT  B              ; invert each bit in the 8-bit value, B
INC  A              ; add 1, giving the 2's complement negated B
ADD  A, B
POP  B              ; restore B
```

Or

```
NOT  B              ; invert each bit in the 8-bit value, B
INC  A              ; add 1, giving the 2's complement negated B
ADD  A, B
NOT  B              ; restore B
```

So that works. But wouldn't it be easier to just have a `SUB` instruction?

```
SUB  A, B
```

If you were writing assembly language to do a lot of arithmetic, which method would you prefer? And, in the first case I used an `INC A` instruction. I could get away without having `INC` and just use `ADD A, 1`. But an `ADD A, 1`, on many microprocessors, requires that I fetch more from the instruction memory to execute in order to obtain the immediate `1` value. Thus, an `INC` is provided since such an operation is so common.

When microprocessor designers determine what instruction set to have, they think about what sorts of operations would be most commonly used. Subtraction is pretty common, so a `SUB` instruction is quite handy to have. Therefore, it exists in just about any instruction set you'll find. There are other instructions in the instruction set whose reason for existence is much less obvious. The x86, for example, has the `XLAT` instruction, and all of the "string" instructions, `LODS`, `STOS`, etc. Why do they exist when I can do all that work with `MOV` and `INC`, etc? Because someone decided that these operations are common enough to merit having a single instruction.

So the purpose behind the `SUB` instruction, like many others implemented by the CPU, is to provide a faster (execution time) and simpler way to perform operations that are most commonly performed in software, balanced with the fact that there's a practical limit to how many instructions can be implemented.

Comment: But I thought that  the assembler automatically creates the 2's complement of a negative operand. Like  in the instruction ADD 1, -2 doesn't the compiler converts the -2 to its 2's complement while assembling the file.

Comment: You're not always work with immediate. That's why in many architectures there are sub between registers but no sub with immediate

Comment: @curious_kid that works great for constants but not registers or memory locations whose values aren't known at assembly time.

Comment: OK that makes sense , so the SUB instruction actually translates to more than one microcode instructions like in the above mentioned answer ?

Comment: @curious_kid no, in the ALU (or before it) there is a NOT gate before 1 operand, and by taking advantage of the carry line we can actually add or subtract in 1 operation with another add/sub selection

Comment: @curious_kid sorry I was using microcode as a more general example, not trying to use it to explain the `SUB` operation specifically. It depends upon the instruction and in the microprocessor. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 13):

## TL;DR

Because it's one of the most common operations, having a dedicated instruction for it helps improving speed. Designers know how to make it fast and a separate negation isn't needed as you think

---

From the famous computer architecture books [*Computer Organization and Design, Fourth Edition: The Hardware/Software Interface*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=3b63x-0P3_UC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=mips+design+principle&source=bl&ots=NzenZ_wcJ2&sig=ALYpDsJIehKGOCXqX4xWSKBuHV8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9LYOVe2GDoeeugSFlILYAg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAzgU#v=onepage&q=mips%20design%20principle&f=false) by David A. Patterson and John L. Hennessy and [*Digital Design and Computer Architecture*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=-DG18Nf7jLcC&pg=PA304&lpg=PA304&dq=mips+design+principle&source=bl&ots=QgqQpFnILJ&sig=U1AXbIHdj8ydB3z2A90h5Y_noVE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9LYOVe2GDoeeugSFlILYAg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgU#v=onepage&q=mips%20design%20principle&f=false) by David Money Harris, Sarah L. Harris we know that MIPS design principles are as below

1. *Design Principle 1:* Simplicity favors regularity.
2. *Design Principle 2:* Make the common case fast.
3. *Design Principle 3:* Smaller is faster.
4. *Design Principle 4:* Good design demands good compromises.

Those are also correct in other architectures. In x86 and many other (mainly older) architectures some cannot be achieved because of backward compatibility, but the main points apply.

Because of the 1<sup>st</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> principles, we need to *make the instruction set as compact as possible* and don't create new instructions if we can do it using other instructions. However as per principles 2 and 4, we need to *make the common operations as fast as possible*.

In fact **most instructions are redundant** as we can have as a Turing complete instruction set with only [one instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9439001/995714). x86 itself is not an OISC architecture but *it's still possible to do anything with just a single `mov` or `add`/`sub`* because they're [proved to be Turing-complete](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Esd601/papers/mov.pdf). There's even a compiler to compile valid C code into a program with only *MOV* (or only either of *XOR, SUB, ADD, XADD, ADC, SBB, AND/OR, PUSH/POP, 1-bit shifts, or CMPXCHG/XCHG*) named [movfuscator](https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/movfuscator)

So with `add` or `sub` we can get shifts, bitwise operations and multiplication/division easily. However those basic operations may need extremely long series of instructions to simulate, and users won't be happy with that.

That's why manufacturers continuously add new instructions to the new microachitectures because newer demands will make things not common before come into use a lot. For example they decided to add [SIMD instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) for vector and 3D operations when 3D applications was becoming a new trend, and matrix operations are also common. And then when increasing security requirements make encryption more common, [AES instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) were introduced to boost cryptography applications. But that's not enough, as cryptography and many other applications use a lot of multiprecision arithmetics, Intel added [MULX/ADOX/ADCX instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_ADX) to make those faster. And now you'll see instructions to accelerate AI operations begin to get into architectures

---

Back to the main question, **subtraction is extremely common so that it's worth a separate instruction**. Without it you'll have to `negate` one operand and then `add`, which cost at least twice the time and instruction space. `sub a, b` is better than `neg b; add a, b`.

However subtraction isn't necessarily slower because of the negation as you thought because **designers use a clever trick to make adders do both `add` and `sub` in the same number of clocks** by adding only a [muxer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer) and a NOT gate along with the new input *Binvert* in order to conditionally invert the second input as below

[image: adder]

[Computer Architecture - Full Adder](http://cs.nyu.edu/%7Egottlieb/courses/2000s/2007-08-fall/arch/lectures/lecture-04.html)

Basic it works by realizing that in two's complement `-b = ~b + 1`, so `a - b = a + ~b + 1`. That means we just need to set the carry in to 1 (or negate the carry in for borrow in) and invert the second input.

This type of [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) was also mentioned in the books I mentioned at the beginning. Unfortunately I can't quote it due to licensing problems, but I've found in another book from prof. Patterson and prof. Hennessy:

[image: RISC-V ALU]

[Computer Organization and Design RISC-V Edition: The Hardware Software Interface](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=H7wxDQAAQBAJ&pg=SL1-PA32&dq=binvert&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim2bCQxPvbAhXEXn0KHTOTCkwQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=binvert&f=false)

As you can see, with another very simple modification they can now do 6 different operations with a single ALU: add, sub, slt, and, or, nor

[image: 6-function ALU]

[CSE 675.02: Introduction to Computer Architecture](https://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/%7Ecrawfis.3/cse675-02/Slides/CSE675_05_ALUDesign.pdf)

In fact designers are very smart at sharing components for saving space, for example they can produce an ALU that works for [both ones' and two's complement](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/21613/1981), or an ALU that shares things with the FPU

You can find more information in ALU design courses, or on Google with the keywords Binvert/Bnegate

- [https://cs.gmu.edu/~setia/cs365-S02/ch4-lec1.pdf](https://cs.gmu.edu/%7Esetia/cs365-S02/ch4-lec1.pdf)
- [http://www.ce.uniroma2.it/~lopresti/Didattica/Arch_Calc/ALU_AppB.pdf](http://www.ce.uniroma2.it/%7Elopresti/Didattica/Arch_Calc/ALU_AppB.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

As others said, a `SUB` instruction is not strictly needed.  For example, on the important PDP-8 computer from 1965 there is no subtraction instruction.  Instead, you have to subtract the other way round.  For example, to compute `A - B` you would do something like this:

```
        / ASSUMING THE ACCUMULATOR AC IS INITIALLY CLEAR
        TAD B           / ADD B TO AC (GIVING B)
        CMA IAC         / COMPLEMENT AND THEN INCREMENT AC (GIVING -B)
        TAD A           / ADD A TO AC (GIVING A - B)
```

Here `TAD` stands for “two's complement add,” `CMA` for “complement accumulator,” and `IAC` for “increment accumulator.”

But that said, you don't even need an `ADD` instruction.  For example, the popular 6502 processor from 1975 famously lacks an `ADD` instruction, having only an `ADC` (add with carry) instruction.  So if you want to do an addition, you first have to ensure the carry flag has been cleared.  This is usually easy to achieve as many instructions clear the carry flag as a side effect.  If that's not the case, you have to manually clear it with a `CLC` instruction.

Likewise, no subtraction instruction existed.  You had to use the `SBC` (subtract with carry) instruction which required you to set the carry flag with a `SEC` instruction beforehand to do a normal subtraction.