# c expression evaluator take 2

Tags: c, expression

In reference to the accepted solution in: [SO:expression_evaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465909/c-expression-evaluator)

Can anyone provide a version that works with negation as well? things like

```
((!(0 or !1) and !((0 or 1 or 1) and !1))
```

need to work as well.

I got it working so that negating the 0's or 1's is fine but I can't get it to work with the negation of whole groups(!'s at beginning of parenthesis)

I tried negating tmp after returning from eval in the *expr == '(' block.. if ! had been seen before calling it, but that didn't work.

Comment: I do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465909/c-expression-evaluator/1472960#1472960

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in that answer is a bit ad-hoc.  Parsing is a well-understood field, there's no need for invention.  One of the other answers there recommends looking into recursive descent parsing.  I second that recommendation.

Comment: +1 - there's nothing more to say, except that one should build something like an AST which can then easily be computed.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm described [here](http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/expression_evaluation.html) can deal with unary operators (operators having one operand), as well as functions.

I once used it as the basis for a complete C expression evaluator with support for symbolic variables for a command-line console on an embedded system.  I did not use the accompanying example code, but rather wrote it from scratch to suit my purposes.