# JITs fundamentals

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, jit

I understand somewhat how "int a = b+abs(c)" can be translated to simple assembly instructions and then translate that to some binary blob. But how can this be run and be interacted with dynamically in memory?

-- edit --

I know C doesn't have an eval feature. But what it's compiled to does. I mean this is what makes Java like JITs, and for that matter, code injection malware possible no? For instance the abs() function is just a pointer, which could be called following the cdecl protocol. New functions should be able to be exposed through passing cdecl function pointers. What I don't understand is how this new code can be injected at runtime.

I'm asking this more of as a longtime academic curiosity, then to most efficiently solve an actual problem.

-- example --

Say I have a piece of embedded python code which is called from a native program a lot, and which also calls a native binding notify():

```
def add(a, b):
    notify()
    return a+b
```

For this to be a point in doing, the function should probably contain quite a bit more code (and way more usefull), but bear with me. A profiler (or hints from the c-bindings) has also identified that all calls are with with integers both with all parameters and return value.
This matches:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    notify();
    return a + b;
}
```

Which could be compiled into an x86 cdecl something similar to this:

```
:_add
push ebp ;setting up scope
mov ebp, esp
call _notify ;or more likely by a pointer reference
mov eax, [ebp + 8]
mov edx, [ebp + 12]
add eax, edx
pop ebp
ret
```

Then finally assembled into a binary string. Of course one would have to implement a basic compiler for each platform to even get this far. But that problem aside, say I now have a char pointer to this valid binary x86 code. Is it somehow possible to extract a cdecl function pointer useable for the native program from this in any way?

Sorry for the unclear intent about my question

Comment: C is normally implemented as a compiled language - you seem to be asking about how C statements can be interpreted. Typically, they can't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the code already compiled in a memory block, and you have the address of the block, it can be casted to a function pointer:

```
typedef int (*func)(int, int);
...
char * compiledCode = ...;
func f = (func) compiledCode;
```

and then the function can be called:

```
int x = f(2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

C lacks any sort of "eval" feature, which is both a limitation and one of the things that allows it to be efficient. If all you need to be able to do is evaluate mathematical expressions with a small set of built-in math functions like `abs()` and not arbitrary C code, it's moderately easy to write such an expression evaluator.

Here's a link to a past SO thread on a similar topic:
[c expression Evaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465909/c-expression-evaluator)

Comment: For just mathematical expressions with moderate performance requirements, you'd be completly right. Updated with original question with clarifications

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. Do you just want to add new functions that can be called, but still only support expression evaluation? Or do you want the full C language (loop constructs, etc.)? If the latter, the only portable solution is to write a full C interpreter or compiler that generates code to run on a virtual machine (which you also need to implement).

If you're not looking for portability, and your platform has shared libraries/dynamic loading, you can run the C compiler and linker to build a new library then load it...

Comment: So basically the only way of running newly machine compiled code, is to create a shared library and load it?

Answer (score 1):

The program must be in memory region that allows execution.

On linux you can do this:

```
void *address;
functype proc;
int prot, flags;

prot = PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC;
flags = MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS;
address = mmap(NULL, length, prot, flags, -1, 0);
if (address == NULL) error;

memcpy(address, program, length);
link(address, program_info);

proc = (functype)address;
```