# Simple library or implementation for a mathematical expression evaluator

Tags: c#, c++, c, c++11

i have one text file that contains only one line the line only contains one math expression
for example 12+(3.0*(4)-1)/sqrt(121)

my program needs to read this express as string and then give the result
13

is there any simple way or 3rd party dll/lib to make this out?

COMMENT ADDED:

[Evaluating a string of simple mathematical expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928563/code-golf-evaluating-mathematical-expressions/944716#944716)

here is the solution but many of the solutions only contain +-/*  acturally ,i need the operators as many as possible  such as ceiling square square root  and power()

so this link maybe is the best solution
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sota_expression_evaluator.aspx

Comment: You want to use C#, C++, _and_ C?

Comment: So in what language you want to implement it?

Comment: My guess is: you're doing this in C#, but you don't want to rule out any C, C++ or C++0x -based possible solutions.

Comment: C#/C/C++/C++0x  any of them are ok but don't give the script or VB ...solutions because i want hook this feature in my C C++ C# project....

Comment: possible duplicate of [c expression Evaluator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465909/c-expression-evaluator)

Comment: VB.net solution will help you perfectly well with a c# project.  that's sort of the point of .net.

Comment: possible duplicate of [operators as strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174664/operators-as-strings)

Answer (score 14):

Using the [**ExprTk**](http://partow.net/programming/exprtk/index.html) library one can easily derive the following *simple* solution:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

#include "exprtk.hpp"

int main()
{
   typedef exprtk::expression<double> expression_t;
   typedef exprtk::parser<double>         parser_t;

   std::string expression_string = "12 + (3.0 * (4) - 1) / sqrt(121)";

   expression_t expression;

   parser_t parser;

   if (parser.compile(expression_string,expression))
   {
     double result = expression.value();

     printf("Result: %19.15\n",result);
   }
   else
     printf("Error in expression\n.");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For C et al, here's a quick-n-dirty and highly unsafe cheat that requires Perl:

```
double eval(const char* expr) {
    char buf[1024];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "perl -e 'print (%s)'", expr);
    FILE* p = popen(buf, "r");
    double d;
    fscanf(p, "%lf", &d);
    fclose(p);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: As you said, a cheat.  Not so much C as it is perl...

Comment: This is great if you don't mind the process overhead and it doesn't require Perl at all--you can invoke something else as a subprocess, e.g. bash `snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "echo $((%s))", expr);`.

Answer (score 1):

.NET solutions:

Here couple of topics on SO:

- [c# evaluating string “3*(4+2)” yield int 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/)
- [Is it possible to translate a user-entered mathematical equation into C# code at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234217/)
- [Is there a string math evaluator in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/)
- [Best and shortest way to evaluate mathematical expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437964/)
- [C# Math calculator (closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859111/c-math-calculator)

---

Also two projects I already used brefore:

C#: [NCalc - Mathematical Expressions Evaluator for .NET](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)

> NCalc is a mathematical expressions evaluator in .NET. NCalc can parse any expression and evaluate the result, including static or dynamic parameters and custom functions.

---

VB.NET: [Fast Lightweight Expression Evaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/)

> Flee is an expression parser and evaluator for the .NET framework. It allows you to compute the value of string expressions such as sqrt(a^2 + b^2) at runtime. It uses a custom compiler, strongly-typed expression language, and lightweight codegen to compile expressions directly to IL. This means that expression evaluation is extremely fast and efficient. Try out the [demo](http://flee.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=demo&referringTitle=Home), which lets you generate images based on expressions, and see for yourself.

You can use it with C# since it .NET anyway (via assembly reference).

Comment: it's complex and the source code is VB, do you have any C# or C++ project like this?

Answer (score 1):

In *The UNIX Programming Environment*, I think it was, a simple calculator called [`hoc`](http://www.google.com/search?q=hoc+calculator) (IIRC) was developed. Possibly its source code is available just about anywhere.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider embedding [lua](http://www.lua.org). Its fast, lightweight and ansi C. And its been specifically designed for embedding. Used by many games as their scripting language. (IMO much easier to embed than python or perl)

Here's a *complete* example to show how trivial it is

```
extern "C"
{
  #include "lua.h"
  #include "lauxlib.h"
  #include "lualib.h"
}

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string expression = "12+(3.0*(4)-1)/math.sqrt(121)";
   lua_State * L = lua_open();
   luaopen_math(L);
   if( luaL_dostring(L, ("return "+expression).c_str()) != 0 )
   {
      std::cout<<"ERROR : "<<lua_tostring(L,-1)<<std::endl;
   }
   if( lua_type(L,-1) == LUA_TNUMBER )
   {
      std::cout<<"GOT "<<lua_tonumber(L,-1)<<std::endl;
   }
   lua_close(L);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you care to brave the source code, you can always look at [`bc`](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bc/). It handles all the Lex/Yacc goodness for you. And if you want a pure C++ solution, you can try coding in [Boost Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/).

Answer (score 0):

For c++, try out muParser:

[muParser - a fast math parser library](http://muparser.sourceforge.net/)