# Console like application in CPP

Tags: c++, parsing, command-prompt

I have been assigned with a coding homework in CPP where I'm supposed to create a Matrix calculator.
This would be an ok-ish task considering all I need to do is matrix calculations, use polymorphism, consider memory consumption, and some more criteria.
What I'm struggling with is that is should be a console like environment.

Meaning  start the app and I'm in a prompt where I type commands like:

scan x[3][3] \n // this creates new matrix labeled 'x' and waits for 9 ints ( longs possibly ) to by typed.

z = add x y \n // or
z = x + y \n

I am familiar with automata theory ( to some degree ) and making it this simple shouldn't be a problem.
( that practically has nothing to do with automata  )
Simple meaning one command per line - because that's what I'm doing now.
I have some parser class that breaks down the command, and than I do the necessary changes. Its more of a if-else tree going from first word to the last. If I encounter unrecognized word - Grammar/Syntax error.

What I'm asking is some tips on how to make it more .. bash like, for instance.
Since the app is run in bash..
FIRST Q: how do i achieve a history of typed commands ? rn when i push arrowup i get those ^[[A.
SECOND Q: Some hints how start parsing some more complicated commands like: a = b = c * ( d + q ) ( implying that 'c' can multiply "(d + q)" and 'd' is *addable* to 'q' etc.. ) bcs that cant be done with the static way my parser works rn.

Thank you all.

Comment: It is rather broad for a question, too for me to try to answer. But as soon as I read *parser*, I always wonder whether lex-yacc (or flex-bison) would be worth it...

Comment: @SergeBallesta going through books you mentioned .. i think what i wished to do, is far beyond what is expected of me. But thank you anyways. Very interesting topic.

Comment: Input in C++ is line-buffered, which means you can only receive input after the user pressed [enter]. To have a "live" interaction you need to look into libraries ike ncurses. Making a list of recent commands should be pretty easy. Reacting to up/down key and updating the display might be the hard part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, look at [`libreadline`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) or [`libeditline`](https://github.com/troglobit/editline). If you do not want to lift a finger, run your program under the [`rlwrap`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) wrapper.

For your second question, look at [Simple library or implementation for a mathematical expression evaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002049/simple-library-or-implementation-for-a-mathematical-expression-evaluator) . Look for one that allows you to define and use variables.