# How to calculate from variable

Tags: php, calculator

```
<?php

// expression is in variable
$var = "1+2*3/4"

// and I want it to perform and show but calculated:
echo $var; // excepted: 2.25

?>
```

So I have calc expressions in variable and I need then to be calculated. Is it possible?

Comment: Remove the quotes from around $var and it should work. since you added quotes PHP is handling this as if it was a string or in other words plain text.. Also there is no way that the solution is 2.25.. Learn about the order of operations 2*3 = 6 / 4 = 1.5 + 1 = 2.5

Comment: To make the operation result in 2.25, you need to write it as `(1+2)*3/4`

Comment: If you MUST keep your quotes (for whatever reason), see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057320/php-function-to-evaluate-string-like-2-1-as-arithmetic-2-1-1

Comment: A safe formula evaluator is available in ircmaxell's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692727/how-to-make-a-calculator-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way is to evaluate the expression.

```
echo eval('echo '.$var.';');
```

which gave me **2.5** bytheway.. and thats the right answer :)

Please consider that eval(); is **dangerous** to expose to anyone, and very hard to secure.

```
"echo 3+4; echo file_get_contents('index.php');"
```

You `eval()` this as a submitted string, and i have the sourcecode of your PHP. Incluing possibly your DB password, which i can now freely connect to, and dump on my screen at my whim. I can also put `unlink('index.php');` in there, which is just plain destructive.

Comment: I would upvote this answer if you warned about the dangerousness of using `eval`.

Comment: You are right. Maybe someone would stop reading at one answer. So i put in some warning :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a function named `eval` that can deal with this but you should take great precautions when using it:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

```
<?php

$var = eval("echo 1+2*3/4;");
echo $var;
// val is 2.5 (2*3/4 is calculated first, then 1 is added to the result)

$var = eval("echo (1+2)*3/4;"); 
echo $var; // val is 2.25
?>
```

for an explanation about why parenthesis is needed, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Most importantly **you need to make sure that the string you send to eval does not contain anything that it shouldn't**

**eval is very dangerous to use. You have been warned**

Comment: does that work without the echo in `eval()`. AFAIK `eval()` returns _output_

Comment: @ThomasMartinKlein Thanks, I have edited the answer now. Seems like a weird way to go, but at least it works. Perhaps just another indication of why it is usually not a good idea to use eval.

Comment: You are welcome. And yes i agree. eval() does have it's uses, but never on the server end of a form.