# add math operators in function php

Tags: php, math

I'm kinda new to this but I was wondering if it is possible to add some dynamic calculation into a function as a parameter.

The thing is inside my function I am formatting stuff in a consistent way but each time I want to add a certain different calculation into the parameter.

```
<?php
function dynamicCalculator($calculation){

 $result = $calculation;

 //some formatting
 return $result;
}

 echo dynamicCalculator('(3x5)+1');
```

This doesn't work of course but if anyone has an idea how this could work I would love to hear it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242/how-to-evaluate-formula-passed-as-string-in-php

Comment: [how to make a calculator in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692727/how-to-make-a-calculator-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the eval function.

```
eval('$result = (3*5)+1');
```

But beware to make sure you're not passing possibly harmful code to that function.

Comment: Thx alot, I was not aware of this eval function, but it does sound 'evil':)  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for RPN (Reverse Polish Notation)

Here is one example

http://pear.php.net/package/Math_RPN/

which would allow you to use

```
$expression = "(2^3)+sin(30)-(!4)+(3/4)";

$rpn = new Math_Rpn(); echo $rpn->calculate($expression,'deg',false);
```

And not have to use Eval

Comment: Suggesting a library is not an answer. Please include valid code, otherwise delete and post as a comment.

Comment: updated with a code example

Comment: Thx alot. I will have a look into this library

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval`. `eval("10+2")` should return 12. Be careful though, you can also run PHP code with `eval`.

Someone else had a [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057320/php-function-to-evaluate-string-like-2-1-as-arithmetic-2-1-1).

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
function dynamicCalculator($calculation) {
   $result = eval($calculation);
   return $result;
}
```

Comment: Note: in the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php it mentions this is dangerous as all sorts of PHP code could be smuggled into `$calculation`.