# Using regex to extract numbers and symbols from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string with text, numbers, and symbols. I'm trying to extract the numbers, and symbols from the string with limited success. Instead of getting the entire number and symbols, I'm only getting part of it. I will explain my regex below, to make it more clearer, and easier to understand.

```
\d : any number
[+,-,*,/,0-9]+ : 1 or more of any +,-,*,/, or number
\d : any number
```

**Code:**

```
$string = "text 1+1-1*1/1= text";

$regex = "~\d[+,-,*,/,0-9]+\d~siU";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches); 

echo $matches[0][0];
```

**Expected Results**

```
1+1-1*1/1
```

**Actual Results**

```
1+1
```

Comment: A big improvement over your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855791/string-to-symbols-and-numbers). Good luck.

Comment: Throw that thing into: https://regex101.com and take a look at the righter upper box

Comment: @Rizier123 Did you see this? \d : any number
[+,-,*,/,0-9]+ : 1 or more of any +,-,*,/, or number
\d : any number

Comment: @jessica Yes, I saw it. And now you probably want to throw your regex ^^ in there and see what it actually does

Comment: It does as I said it does above. Do you see the expected results, and the actual results above in bold? That's the results. Same in regex101.

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm asking WHY it does that even though my regex expression is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the U flag. It's causing the the `+` to be nongreedy  in its matching. Also, you don't need commas between characters in your character list. (You only need 1 `,` if you're trying match it. You do need to escape `-` so that it doesn't think you're trying to make a range

Comment: :) Finally. Someone who found the problem! It seems siU was completely unnecessary in the regex above. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @jessica np. Does it really still work with the commas? (Never tried that before and can't test from my phone

Comment: No. I've already removed the commas, as the commas were part of the problem, as @dxdy pointed out. But I think the siU were the main part of the problem, and since you addressed both the commas and the siU, you have the best answer.

Comment: @jessica I told you tu remove the 'U' flag but i think you just completely ignored the 'get rid of the 'U' flag"...

Comment: @vinxce when you said "for small things like that..." it was unclear that that the U flag was the problem. Edit it into your answer and take an upvote

Comment: @Vinxce Since you ignored my comment, I thought it would only be right if I ignore yours in reciprocation. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your regex does mix up quite a few unescaped metacharacters. In your character class you have `[+,-,*,/,0-9]`. You do not need to separate different characters with commas, that will only tell the regex-engine to include commas in your expression. Furthermore, you need to escape the -, as it has a special meaning inside the character class. As it is, it will be interpreted as 'characters from "," to "," instead of the literal character "-". A similar problem exists with the "/"-character. The expression `\d[+\-*/0-9]+\d` should do the trick.

Comment: ...Your eyes are misleading you...I DO already have a + sign at the end.

Comment: My eyes were indeed misleading me. Sorry about that. The problem lies somewhere else, check out the edited answer.

Comment: As far as I know meta characters does not need to be escaped inside [] brackets.

Comment: Most of them do not, but some do indeed. Among them are `\ ^ ] -`. Consider this, how else is the engine supposed to know whether `0-9` means "the characters from 0 to 9" or "the characters 0,- and 9".

Comment: Only \, are consider actual commas. The other un-escaped commas are considered as separators.

Comment: Unfortunately, the syntax does not work this way. Compare with [this](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) page from the documentation. It explicitly states that "The minus (hyphen) character can be used to specify a range of characters in a character class. For example, [d-m] matches any letter between d and m, inclusive. If a minus character is required in a class, it must be escaped with a backslash or appear in a position where it cannot be interpreted as indicating a range, typically as the first or last character in the class."

Comment: @jessica I said, you should throw that regex in there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856068/using-regex-to-extract-numbers-and-symbols-from-string#comment53545709_32856068

Comment: @dxdy It seems that you are correct. My apologies. However, \ does not need to be escaped inside [] brackets. Also, you seem to have missed a comma when you were removing them, in your answer "\d[+\-,*\/0-9]+\d".

Comment: @dxdy Still. You made an effort in trying to help me so I'll give you an upvote for effort.

Comment: I did indeed miss that comma. Edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score -3):

Didn't test it with your code but should work :)

```
((?:[0-9]+[\+|\-|\*|\/]?)+)
```

More in details, if you want to understand my pattern : https://regex101.com/r/mF0zO8/2

Comment: For small strings like that you can get rid of the U flag :)

Comment: You seem to ignore the comment "It doesn't work", completely.