# How to do math with a string?

Tags: php

So lets show an example here shall we?

Let's say I have 2 strings that are like this....

```
$math1 = "+300";
$math2 = "-125";
```

So obviously the answer would have to be +175 but how do I actually do the math while the input is a string.

I can't simply do

```
$math1 - $math2
```

Because it'd have to figure out if it is a + or a -, so how can this exactly be done?

Comment: You have to know what number you're subtracting from what number: `$result = $math1 - abs($math2);` or `$result = $math1 + $math2;`

Comment: Well the thing is, the operations could be different. It's data that would come from the database and come out as a string. So it could be -300 or +300 or even x300.

Comment: so cast it as an integer if you're forced to using strings

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242/how-to-evaluate-formula-passed-as-string-in-php or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057320/php-function-to-evaluate-string-like-2-1-as-arithmetic-2-1-1 ?

Comment: 300 - (-125) = 425, whereas 300 - (125) = 175. both come back as `int`. php is a loose type language, it can do the math directly. simply `$math1 - $math2` return correct result

Answer (score 0):

You can use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to get the integer value of a variable, and then you can do basic math operations.

```
<?php
    $math1 = intval("+300");
    $math2 = intval("-125");
    echo $math1 - $math2;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intval($math1) + intval($math2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be:

```
$result = abs($math1) - abs($math2);
```