# Only PHP Code Calculator with Clickable Buttons as Input

Tags: php, html, forms, input, calculator

I am trying to code a calculator with only PHP and HTML code.

The Calculator should look like a real one and the buttons should be clickable.

Right now, I am stuck at combining 2 numbers, this means I press one button the number will be shown. But after I press the second button the first value disappears because of the `type="submit"`.

My Question is: How can I save the value and show all pressed buttons together?

I know I can do that with a hidden input, but I don't know how to use them properly.

Also how am I able to calculate the whole expression after doing that?

I know javascript or any other client-side language would be better, but I want to find a way to do it purely with PHP and HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Taschenrechner</title>
        <link href="Stylesheets/Stylesheets.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['zahl'])){
    $zahl1 = $_POST['zahl'];
}else{
    $zahl1 = 0;
}
?>

<form name="rechner" action="rechner.php" method="post">
    <input id="feld1" type="hidden" name="zahl1" value="">
    <input id="feld2" type="hidden" name="opera" value="">
    <input id="feld3" type="hidden" name="zahl2" value="">
    <input id="feld4" type="hidden" name="zwischerg" value=>
    <table align="center" style="width:300px; height:450px; border:solid thick black;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input id="display" type="text" name="bildschirm" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: center; height: 50px; width: 216px;" value=<?php echo $zahl1; $op; $zahl2 ?>>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="zahl" value="1" >
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="zahl" value="2">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="zahl" value="3">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="operator" value="+">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="zahl" value="4">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="zahl" value="5">
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="zahl" value="6">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="operator" value="-">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="zahl" value="7">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="zahl" value="8">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="zahl" value="9">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="operator" value="*">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="clear" value="C">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="zahl" value="0">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="zahl" value=".">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="taste" type="submit" name="operator" value="/">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            <input type="submit" name="gleich" value="=" style=" width: 215px; height: 50px;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unless want a calculator which literally refreshes the page every click, you should probably use JavaScript or something for this.

Comment: Yah, thanks but ive already figured this out. But there must be any possibility to do this with php only or am i wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use javascript instead of php? PHP is a server side and your calculator can easily be created with javascript on browser here is the nice tutorial you can follow: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631525/Creating-Calculator-using-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript

Comment: At the moment i am learning PHP and i want to understand what is possible and what doesnt work. Ive already found a couple of Javascript Calculators that worked, but nothing with only PHP. Sorry for the bad englisch btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my truly basic, almost style-less, pure-PHP calculator form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Basic PHP Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//var_export($_POST);
//echo "<br>";
$buttons = [1,2,3,'+',4,5,6,'-',7,8,9,'*','C',0,'.','/','='];
$pressed = '';
if (isset($_POST['pressed']) && in_array($_POST['pressed'], $buttons)) {
    $pressed = $_POST['pressed'];
}
$stored = '';
if (isset($_POST['stored']) && preg_match('~^(?:[\d.]+[*/+-]?)+$~', $_POST['stored'], $out)) {
    $stored = $out[0];  
}
$display = $stored . $pressed;
//echo "$pressed & $stored & $display<br>";
if ($pressed == 'C') {
    $display = '';
} elseif ($pressed == '=' && preg_match('~^\d*\.?\d+(?:[*/+-]\d*\.?\d+)*$~', $stored)) {
    $display .= eval("return $stored;");
}

echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">";
    echo "<table style=\"width:300px;border:solid thick black;\">";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan=\"4\">$display</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        foreach (array_chunk($buttons, 4) as $chunk) {
            echo "<tr>";
                foreach ($chunk as $button) {
                    echo "<td",(count($chunk) != 4 ? " colspan=\"4\"" : "") , "><button name=\"pressed\" value=\"$button\">$button</button></td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"stored\" value=\"$display\">";
echo "</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot while I was testing:

[image]

You can see that I've made every button a submit button with the same name, but different values.  I use a single hidden input to preserve built expression.  There will be many enhancements and considerations beyond this demo, it is up to you how far to go down this rabbit hole.

---

P.S. For anyone who just unholstered their sidearm, squinted one eye, and sternly uttered "***Hey, we don't take kindly to folks like you callin' `eval()` in these here parts!***".  Well, I've endeavored to adequately validate the string to be evaluated.  If there is a known hole, please let me know and I'll try to fix it.  Alternatively, this is my attempt to re-invent the `eval()` process with BOMDAS in mind:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/d5RoU))

```
$stored = "2+3*4/6";
$components = preg_split('~([*/+-])~', $stored, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
while (($index = array_search('*', $components)) !== false) {
    array_splice($components, $index - 1, 3, $components[$index - 1] * $components[$index + 1]);
}
while (($index = array_search('/', $components)) !== false) {
    array_splice($components, $index - 1, 3, $components[$index - 1] / $components[$index + 1]);
}
while (($index = array_search('+', $components)) !== false) {
    array_splice($components, $index - 1, 3, $components[$index - 1] + $components[$index + 1]);
}
while (($index = array_search('-', $components)) !== false) {
    array_splice($components, $index - 1, 3, $components[$index - 1] - $components[$index + 1]);
}
echo current($components);  // 4
```

Comment: At first thank you for your Example.
But i found a little Bug in there that made it impossible to run it properly.
If i cut the part of preg_match out it works without problems also i need to change the $stored from  $stored=$out[0]; to  $stored=$_POST['stored'];
Without changing it isnt able to type more than 4 numbers in display.
Sorry for double posting

Comment: I was online from my smartphone. And the green tick wasn't there so I clicked it again.