# Split mathematic expression into array without splitting subexpressions between parentheses and single quotes

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-split, mathematical-expressions

Let's say I have this string:

```
1 + 2 * (3 + (23 + 53 - (132 / 5) + 5) - 1) + 2 / 'test + string' - 52
```

I want to split it into an array of operators and non-operators, but anything between the `()` and `'` must not be split.

I want the output to be:

```
[1, "+", 2, "*", "(3 + (23 + 53 - (132 / 5) + 5) - 1)", "+", 2, "/", "'test + string'", "-", 52]
```

I'm using this code:

```
preg_split("~['\(][^'()]*['\)](*SKIP)(*F)|([+\-*/^])+~", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

The technique does what I want with the operators and the `'`, but not for `()`. However it only keeps `(132 / 5)` (the deepest nested parenthetical expression) and splits all the other ones, giving me this output:

```
[1, "+", 2, "*", "(3", "+", "(23", "+", 53, "-", "(132 / 5)", "+", "5)", "-", "1)", "+", 2, "/", "'test + string'", "-", 52]
```

How can I ensure that the outermost parenthetical expression and all of its contents remain together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a pattern to recurse the first sub pattern matching balanced parenthesis and then use the SKIP FAIL. After the alternation you can still use the capture group, which will be group 2 and the values will be kept due to the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag.

To remove the empty entries, you can add the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag.

```
(?:(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*F)|([+\-*/^])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ufkwYh/1)

```
$str = "1 + 2 * (3 + (23 + 53 - (132 / 5) + 5) - 1) + 2 / 'test + string' - 52";
$result = preg_split("~(?:(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*F)|([+\-*/^])~", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => +
    [2] =>  2 
    [3] => *
    [4] =>  (3 + (23 + 53 - (132 / 5) + 5) - 1) 
    [5] => +
    [6] =>  2 
    [7] => /
    [8] =>  'test + string' 
    [9] => -
    [10] =>  52
)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for letting me know, this works perfectly, also, I figured out another way for doing what I wanted, which is:  `('[^']*'|(\(.+\)))(*SKIP)(*F)|([+\-*/^]+)`

Comment: @SaifAlhammouri You are welcome. For your example string that would work, but note that when you for example add parenthesis at the end of the string it would not give the expected matches https://regex101.com/r/QdtBK5/1

Comment: Oh, I didn't test it that way, thank you so much for letting me know, I'll be using your way.

Answer (score 2):

I do like @thefourthbird's recursive subpattern, but I would prefer to standardize the output elements so that all whitespace is removed.

I won't use delimiter capturing or skip-fail, but fullstring restarts (`\K`) to omit the spaces.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iGXQj))

```
preg_split(
    "~(?:(\((?:[^()]+|(?1))*\))|'[^']*'|[\d.]+|[*/^+-])\K ?~",
    $str,
    -1,
    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
)
```

I have done [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45985538/2943403) techniques on SO like this one.  Another consideration is: how do you want to handle signed numbers? Should the numberic entity retain the sign symbol or should it be separated as if it were an operator?

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying, I actually wanted to keep all the spaces as they are, but I appreciate your reply.

Comment: Okay, that's not what your question's desired output says.  In that case, just remove the space-question after the `\K` in my pattern.  https://3v4l.org/EVCSa

Comment: Ah, sorry my bad, but thank you very much.